# Bootstrap table move columns dynamically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table of 6 columns. I am trying to get the 2 first pulled to the left, and the 4 last pulled to the right. I want them to stack up from the two sides, depending on the size of their content. I mean that if for example the two last have no content, they should all be sticked to the right border. But if the last one has a content which needs x pixels to be displayed, the 5th one should be moved of x pixels to the left starting from the right border.

I tried to do that adding pull-right and pull-left classes to my td tags, and it works well in terms of position, but it made my border between rows disappear, and I figured out thanks to that that blank space was left between the columns. In the rows, there were spaces which weren't included in any column.

I am looking for a clean way to do that kind of design, because this doesn't seem proper at all. It also needs to be responsive. Thank you in advance for sharing your ideas !

Edit : here is my code, it's in erb so just focus on the classes, and there's not any separate CSS related with the custom classes, it's only bootstrap :

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive cards-table">
          <tbody>
          <% @cards_not_completed.each do |card| %>
              <tr class="cards-row-clickable" data-link='<%= edit_card_path(card) %>' data-params="<%= params[:page_completed] %>@!<%= params[:page_not_completed] %>">
                <td class="checkbox-column pull-left">
                  <%= form_for card, :html => {:class => "checkbox_completed_card"}, remote: true do |f| %>
                      <%= f.check_box :is_completed %>
                  <% end %>
                </td>
                <td class="title-column pull-left"><%= card.title %></td>
                <td class="dueat-column pull-right"><%= card.due_at %></td>
                <td class="creator-column pull-right"><%= User.find(card.user_id).email %></td>
                <td class="assignee-column pull-right">
                  <% if !card.assignee_id.blank? %><%= User.find(card.assignee_id).email %>
                  <% end %>
                </td>
                <td class="destroy-column pull-right">
                  <%= link_to card, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?', params: {page_completed: params[:page_completed].to_param, page_not_completed: params[:page_not_completed].to_param}}, remote: true do %>
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                  <% end %>
                </td>
              </tr>
          <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: edit your question and hit CTRL + M and paste all the html and css that you have tried

Comment: @mlegg That's done, I didn't want to do it because of the erb which is a bit confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it merging all the columns that needed to be pulled to the right in one, and generating its content dynamically. Thanks to that, I have two columns on the left, always filled, and one on the right that is filled dynamically and takes the space it needs thanks to the flex attribute. I added `style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"` to the row and `style="text-align: right; flex: 1;"` to my right column. This way, the content is stacked up on the right.

See :

```html
<tr style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;" class="cards-row-clickable" data-link='<%= edit_card_path(card) %>' data-params="<%= params[:page_completed] %>@!<%= params[:page_not_completed] %>">
                  <td class="checkbox-column">
                    <%= form_for card, :html => {:class => "checkbox_completed_card"}, remote: true do |f| %>
                        <%= f.check_box :is_completed %>
                    <% end %>
                  </td>
                  <td class="title-column" style="overflow: hidden;"><%= card.title %></td>
                  <td class="info-column" style="text-align: right; flex: 1;">
                    <% if !card.due_at.blank? %>
                        <span style="color:red;"><%= card.due_at %> </span>
                    <% end %>
                    <span>Creator : <%= card.user.email %></span>

                    <% if !card.assignee_id.blank? %>
                        <span>, assignee : <%= User.find(card.assignee_id).email.slice(0..(User.find(card.assignee_id).email.index('@')-1)) %></span>
                    <% end %>

                    <%= link_to card, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?', params: {page_completed: params[:page_completed].to_param, page_not_completed: params[:page_not_completed].to_param}}, remote: true do %>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    <% end %>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```